# NodeJs route does not render

Tags: node.js, express, path, routes

I am building an Express app and having some issues with routing. 
This is my routes.js

```
const EDIT_VIDEO = "/edit";
const routes = {
  editVideo: (id) => {
    if (id) {
      return `videos/${id}/edit`;
    } else {
      return EDIT_VIDEO;
    }
  },
  deleteVideo: DELETE_VIDEO,
};

export default routes;
```

This is my videoController:

```
import Video from "../models/Video";
import routes from "../routes";


export const getEditVideo = async (req, res) => {
  const {
    params: { id },
  } = req;
  try 
    const video = await Video.findById(id);
    res.render("editVideo", { pageTitle: `Edit ${video.title}`, video });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    res.redirect(routes.home);
  }
};
export const postEditVideo = (req, res) => {};
```

This is my videoRouter:

```
import express from "express";
import routes from "../routes";
import {
  getEditVideo,
  postEditVideo,
} from "../controllers/videoController";

const videoRouter = express.Router();

/*------Video Routes------*/
//Edit
videoRouter.get(routes.editVideo(), getEditVideo);
videoRouter.post(routes.editVideo(), postEditVideo);
export default videoRouter;
```

When I go to 'videos/"id"/edit' I see this error in the browser - Cannot GET /videos/5ed2a169eb370432c01f5ebd/edit

I have a pug template named "editVideo.pug" in views directory and I have not idea why it is not working.

Comment: Your routes should start with `/`.  So, this `videos/${id}/edit`  should be `/videos/${id}/edit`.

Comment: FYI, this is a bizarre way to do things where it looks like you're adding an individual route for every single existing id.  That's pretty cumbersome as your server may end up with zillions of routes and a slower process to match all of them and no way to ever remove one.  Usually, you would use a route like `/videos/:id/edit` and then dynamically use the id in the `getEditVideo` from req.params.id where Express will put it for you.  Is there a reason you're not doing it that way?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I changed the route but I still get the same error. And yes, I know about REST routing, I just saw this way of routing and I was trying it by myself, but you are right the /videos/:id/edit way is more dynamically. Thank you

Comment: Where does `id` come from in videoController.js?  I don't see it defined anywhere.